# My game keeps freezing, I've tried a lot but I've had no progress

Tags: javascript, html

So I've been working on a side project to make a game and practice coding. The game I've been making so far has been rudimentary, but progress has been steady. After looking through the code several times, I have not been able to find the root of the problem.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Jump Test</title>
    <style>
        #player {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0px;
            top: 0px;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: rgb(153, 0, 255);
            box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgb(23, 6, 255);
        }
        #ground {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: black;
        }
        #scoreboard {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            right: 10px;
            font-size: 24px;
            color: white;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            background-color: black;
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }
        #distance-scoreboard {
            position: absolute;
            top: 60px;
            right: 10px;
            font-size: 24px;
            color: white;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            background-color: black;
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            
        }
        #enemy {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0px;
            top: 850px;
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
            box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="player"></div>
    <div id="ground"></div>
    <div id="enemy"></div>
    <div id="scoreboard">Jumps: 0</div>
    <div id="distance-scoreboard">Distance Traveled: 0 cm</div>

<script>
// Define variables
// Get the elements from the HTML DOM and assign them to variables
let player = document.querySelector('#player');
let ground = document.querySelector('#ground');
let enemy = document.querySelector("#enemy");
let scoreboard = document.querySelector('#scoreboard');
let distanceScoreboard = document.querySelector('#distance-scoreboard');

// Declare and initialize game variables
let jumpsCount = 0;
let velocity = 0;
let gravity = 0.2;
let movingLeft = false;
let movingRight = false;
let jumpKeyDown = false;
let Jumps = 0;
let distanceTraveled = 0;
let horizontalDistance = 0;
let verticalDistance = 0;
let enemyPosition = 1500;
let enemyVelocity = 0;
let enemySpeed = 7;

// Define functions

// Function to make the player jump
function jump() {
// If the player hasn't jumped yet and is on the ground, set their velocity to a negative value to make them jump
if (jumpsCount < 1 && player.offsetTop + player.offsetHeight >= ground.offsetTop) {
velocity = -8;
jumpsCount++;
Jumps++;
// Update the scoreboard to display the number of jumps
scoreboard.textContent = 'Jumps: ' + Jumps;
}
}

// Function to make the enemy jump if the player is above it
function enemyJump() {
if (player.offsetTop + player.offsetHeight < enemy.offsetTop && enemyVelocity === 0) {
enemyVelocity = -7;
}
}

// Function to check if the player is within range of the enemy and if so, make the enemy jump
function checkPlayerInRange(player) {
const playerBox = player.getBoundingClientRect();
const enemyBox = enemy.getBoundingClientRect();

if (playerBox.bottom >= enemyBox.top &&
playerBox.top <= enemyBox.bottom &&
playerBox.right >= enemyBox.left &&
playerBox.left <= enemyBox.right &&
enemyVelocity >= 0) {
enemyVelocity = -7;
}
}

// Function to calculate the distance traveled by the player
function calculateDistanceTraveled() {
let currentHorizontalDistance = player.offsetLeft;
let currentVerticalDistance = player.offsetTop;
let currentDistanceInCm = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(currentHorizontalDistance - horizontalDistance, 2) + Math.pow(currentVerticalDistance - verticalDistance, 2)) / 10; // divide by 10 to convert to cm

// If the current distance is 0, exit the function
if (currentDistanceInCm === 0) {
return;
}

// Add the current distance traveled to the total distance traveled
distanceTraveled += currentDistanceInCm;

// Update the distance scoreboard with the current distance traveled
if (distanceTraveled >= 100000) {
let distanceInKilometers = distanceTraveled / 100000;
distanceScoreboard.textContent = "Distance Traveled: " + distanceInKilometers.toFixed(2) + " km";
} else if (distanceTraveled >= 100) {
let distanceInMeters = distanceTraveled / 100;
distanceScoreboard.textContent = "Distance Traveled: " + distanceInMeters.toFixed(2) + " m";
} else {
distanceScoreboard.textContent = "Distance Traveled: " + distanceTraveled.toFixed(2) + " cm";
}

// Update the horizontal and vertical distances for the next calculation
horizontalDistance = currentHorizontalDistance;
verticalDistance = currentVerticalDistance;
}


// This function is responsible for animating the game by calling itself recursively with requestAnimationFrame
function animate() {
requestAnimationFrame(animate);

// Call functions to move enemy, check if player is in range, and check for collisions
moveEnemy();
checkPlayerInRange(player);
checkCollision();

// If jump key is pressed, call jump function
if (jumpKeyDown) {
jump();
}

// Add gravity to the player's velocity
velocity += gravity;

// Calculate new top position for the player
let newTop = player.offsetTop + velocity;

// Check if player has hit the ground and reset jumpsCount if they have
if (newTop + player.offsetHeight >= ground.offsetTop) {
newTop = ground.offsetTop - player.offsetHeight;
jumpsCount = 0;
}

// Check if player has gone above the top of the screen and set their top position to 0 if they have
if (newTop < 0) {
newTop = 0;
}

// Set the player's top position to the new top position
player.style.top = newTop + 'px';

// Calculate new left position for the player
let newLeft = player.offsetLeft;

// If movingLeft is true, move the player to the left
if (movingLeft) {
newLeft = player.offsetLeft - 5;
}

// If movingRight is true, move the player to the right
if (movingRight) {
newLeft = player.offsetLeft + 5;
}

// Check if player has gone beyond the left side of the screen and set their left position to 0 if they have
if (newLeft < 0) {
newLeft = 0;
}

// Check if player has gone beyond the right side of the screen and set their left position to the maximum possible if they have
if (newLeft + player.offsetWidth > window.innerWidth) {
newLeft = window.innerWidth - player.offsetWidth;
}

// Set the player's left position to the new left position
player.style.left = newLeft + 'px';

// Call function to calculate the distance the player has traveled
calculateDistanceTraveled();
}


function moveEnemy() {

  // Calculate distance between player and enemy
  let distanceToPlayer = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(player.offsetLeft - enemyPosition, 2));


  // Follow the player when the player is within 750 pixels of the enemy
  if (distanceToPlayer <= 750) {
    // Update enemySpeed to follow the player
    if (player.offsetLeft < enemyPosition) {
      enemySpeed = -7;
    } else {
      enemySpeed = 7;
    }

    // Jump if player is above enemy and within 100 pixels on both sides
    let playerAbove = player.offsetTop + player.offsetHeight < enemy.offsetTop;
    let playerInRange = distanceToPlayer <= 100;
    if (playerAbove && playerInRange) {
      jumpEnemy();
    }
  } else { // Perform searching behavior
    // Move enemy towards nearest wall
    if (enemyPosition < window.innerWidth / 2) {
      enemySpeed = 7;
    } else {
      enemySpeed = -7;
    }

    // Turn around when enemy reaches wall
    if (enemyPosition <= 0 || enemyPosition + enemy.offsetWidth >= window.innerWidth) {
      enemySpeed = -enemySpeed;
    }
  }

  // Update enemy position
  enemyPosition += enemySpeed;

  // Ensure enemy stays within the screen boundaries
  if (enemyPosition < 0) {
    enemyPosition = 0;
  } else if (enemyPosition + enemy.offsetWidth > window.innerWidth) {
    enemyPosition = window.innerWidth - enemy.offsetWidth;
  }

  // Update enemy position and velocity
  enemy.style.left = enemyPosition + 'px';
  enemyVelocity += gravity;
  let newTop = enemy.offsetTop + enemyVelocity;

  // Stop enemy from falling below ground
  if (newTop + enemy.offsetHeight >= ground.offsetTop) {
    newTop = ground.offsetTop - enemy.offsetHeight;
    enemyVelocity = 0;
  }

  // Stop enemy from moving above the screen
  if (newTop < 0) {
    newTop = 0;
  }

  // Update enemy vertical position
  enemy.style.top = newTop + 'px';
}


function checkCollision() {
  if (
    player.offsetLeft + player.offsetWidth >= enemy.offsetLeft &&
    player.offsetLeft <= enemy.offsetLeft + enemy.offsetWidth &&
    player.offsetTop + player.offsetHeight >= enemy.offsetTop &&
    player.offsetTop <= enemy.offsetTop + enemy.offsetHeight
  ) {
    // player collides with enemy
    // alert('Game over!');
  } else if (
    enemy.offsetTop + enemy.offsetHeight >= player.offsetTop &&
    enemy.offsetLeft + enemy.offsetWidth >= player.offsetLeft &&
    enemy.offsetLeft <= player.offsetLeft + player.offsetWidth
  ) {
    // enemy collides with player
    enemyJump();
  } else if (
    player.offsetTop + player.offsetHeight >= enemy.offsetTop + enemy.offsetHeight &&
    player.offsetLeft + player.offsetWidth >= enemy.offsetLeft &&
    player.offsetLeft <= enemy.offsetLeft + enemy.offsetWidth
  ) {
    // player passes underneath enemy
    if (enemyVelocity > 0) {
      enemyJump(); // make the enemy jump if it's falling
    }
  }
}
// Add event listeners
document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
  if (event.code === 'Space' && jumpsCount < 1) {
    jump();
    jumpKeyDown = true;
  } else if (event.code === 'KeyA') {
    movingLeft = true;
  } else if (event.code === 'KeyD') {
    movingRight = true;
  }
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
  if (event.code === 'KeyA') {
    movingLeft = false;
  } else if (event.code === 'KeyD') {
    movingRight = false;
  } else if (event.code === 'Space') {
    jumpKeyDown = false;
  }
});

// Call the animate function to start
checkCollision();
animate();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm certain the problem lies with the movement functions, but I cant figure out which. This is where I could use your help.

I have tried removing the functionality of the checkCollision() function using comments. This didn't work as the game continues freezing when the player and enemy characters get close enough.

I have tried removing the functionality of the moveEnemy() function using comments, which fixed the game from freezing, at the cost of the enemy character's movement.

I have tried commenting the code in sections, running by and attempting to debug the code. The bug remained.

Comment: It isn't really frozen, your enemy is just repeatedly moving left 7px, then right 7px, for infinity.  The logic in your moveEnemy is flawed in some way, I think the "perform searching behavior" in particular - looks like when your enemy is on the left half of the screen, it moves right, but when on the right half, it moves left, and so gets stuck on the midcourt line.  But without knowing what the intended behavior is, it's hard to say for sure.  I would suggest setting some breakpoints in your `moveEnemy` using the browser dev tools, or providing some more details in your question.

Comment: As a note, it is generally good practice to split your HTML, CSS, and scripts into separate files.  This will prevent you from having to do all your work in one giant HTML file, will let you get better intellisense and styling from your IDE, and makes debugging things in the dev tools a lot easier (and also allows you to use StackSnippets more easily as well).